# Unable to set Attached Property in a Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I have a `Style` in a custom control, in which I am trying to set an attached property on a `Label`.

**The Style**

```xml
<Style x:Key="DayNumberStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="local:DateRangePickerHelper.SelectionType" Value="Selected"></Setter>
</Style>
```

**The Attached Property**

```cs
public class DateRangePickerHelper : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DateSelectionType", typeof(DateSelectionType), typeof(DateRangePickerHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(DateSelectionType.NotSelected));

    public static void SetSelectionType(DependencyObject element, DateSelectionType value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SelectionTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public static DateSelectionType GetSelectionType(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (DateSelectionType)element.GetValue(SelectionTypeProperty);
    }
}
```

**The Enum**

```cs
public enum DateSelectionType
{
    NotSelected,
    Selected,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
}
```

**The Label**

```xml
<Label Style="{StaticResource DayNumberStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Sunday}">
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>                                                                                
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">                                                                                    
         <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LabelClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DateRangePicker}}"                                                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Sunday}"></b:InvokeCommandAction>                                                                                
      </b:EventTrigger>                                                                            
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Label>
```

**The Error**

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'property')

When I remove the attached property from the `Setter` everything works correctly.

Can someone explain why I cannot set this with the `Style` `Setter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a dependency property `SelectionTypeProperty`, so its name must be `SelectionType`, as your can read in the documentation: [How to implement a dependency property (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property?view=netdesktop-6.0)

> The identifier field must follow the naming convention `<property name>Property`. For instance, if you register a dependency property with the name `Location`, then the identifier field should be named `LocationProperty`.

However, in your definition, you pass `DateSelectionType` name, which is the name of the *type of the property*, but not the *name of the property* itself.

> If you fail to follow this naming pattern, then WPF designers might not report your property correctly, and **aspects of the property system style application might not behave as expected**.

Change the name to `SelectionType` and it works as expected.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "SelectionType", typeof(DateSelectionType), typeof(DateRangePickerHelper),
     new PropertyMetadata(DateSelectionType.NotSelected));
```

In case you ever implement a regular dependency property that has property wrappers instead of methods, you could use `nameof(<YourProperty>)` to prevent this and renaming issues.